# Clojure namespaces

Tags: clojure

I want to split a big clojure-script into smaller ones. And it looks like this.

One:

```
(ns one
  (:use [two :only (show)]))

(def status "WORKING")
```

Two:

```
(ns two
  (:use [one :only (status)]))

(defn show [] (println status))
```

Result: **Exception**.

**PS** I understand that some some kind of recursive namespace constructing happens. I know only a sloppy half-solution, like **defining** *without body* **before** referncing to namespaces? Any suggestions?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

+1 for the answer of ponzao. To elaborate a bit more: Cyclic dependencies of namespaces are often a sign, that you didn't get your abstractions and/or APIs right. Either you "mix" layers or things should just be in one namespace, because the really belong together.

If you want to just split one namespace into several files, this is also possible.

name/space.clj:

```
(ns name.space)

(declare status)

(load "space_one")
(load "space_two")
```

name/space_one.clj:

```
(in-ns 'name.space)
(defn show [] (println status))
```

name/space_two.clj:

```
(in-ns 'name.space)
(def status "WORKING")
```

Comment: Clojure does not support cyclic dependencies between namespaces. You have to design to avoid it.

Comment: @stuart-sierra Did I say something different?

Answer (score 6):

You are constructing a cyclic dependency between two components, are you sure this is what you want? Why not have a third namespace containing their common functions?

Comment: I **don't** want to **over-engineer** a simple project by making to many layers of abstractions and etc. One file keeps data, settings, and everything for processing. I wan't to use it as part of web-service. But for desktop-debugging i use simple visualization, which reads settings from main script, but gives a single function to show this thing on a screen. Thank you.